# git pull accept theirs/ours

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

Можно ли как-то заставить git во время pull-а использовать стратегию слияния theirs для конкретной директории? Но если конфликты возникнут в других местах - пусть предоставить мне возможность решать.

Сейчас в голову приходит только такое:
делаем hook, который отрабатывает после pull-а, и запускает `git checkout --theirs {моя директория}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

на основе ответа: [Simple tool to 'accept theirs' or 'accept mine' on a whole file using git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17227804/4827341)

---

для частичной автоматизации можно, например, использовать псевдонимы:

```
$ git config --global alias.accept-ours = "!f() { [ -z \"$@\" ] && set - '.'; git checkout --ours -- \"$@\"; git add -u -- \"$@\"; }; f"
$ git config --global alias.accept-theirs = "!f() { [ -z \"$@\" ] && set - '.'; git checkout --theirs -- \"$@\"; git add -u -- \"$@\"; }; f"
```

и при возникновении конфликта после `git pull` для файлов/каталогов, которые должны быть `ours`, выполнить:

```
$ git accept-ours -- файлы/каталоги ...
```

а для тех, что должны быть `theirs`:

```
$ git accept-theirs -- файлы/каталоги ...
```