# Авторесолв конфликта в конкретном файле

Tags: git, git-merge

Есть файл, в котором при мёрдже часто возникают конфликты. Хочу чтобы в автоматическом режиме выбиралась любая из версий файла, а потом запускалась программа, которая перегенерирует фрагмент этого файла. Как такое реализовать?

Можно запускать программу при любом мёрдже, независимо от наличия конфликтов, но только в том случае, если создаётся мёрдж-коммит. Если же выполняется fast forward, то он должен успешно выполниться без лишнего коммита.

---

Полная схема:

- Нажимаю кнопочку merge в SourceTree и выбираю ветку
- Происходит мёрдж

  - Если был выполнен fast forward, заканчиваем
  - В файле smth.xml произошёл мёрдж-конффликт?

    - Да: запустить программу, которая этот файл помёрджит
    - Нет: не важно, будет ли запущена программа, которая его меняет
  - Конфликты остались?

    - Да: заканчиваем
    - Нет: мёрдж-коммит коммитится
      Обращаю внимание, что если конфликтов не было, но программа была запущена, то изменённый файл должен быть закоммичен в единственном мёрдж-коммите (т. е. ое НЕ должен остаться незакоммиченным и он НЕ должен коммититься отдельным коммитом).

Comment: а указание *merge strategy* не помогает?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, а можно поподробнее?

Comment: [другие типы слияний](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, но мне не нужно трогать другие конфликты, если они есть.

Comment: [а поиск таки рулит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/475552/178576)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, интересно, но там тоже же команду с алиасом надо руками вводить?

Comment: перечитал ещё раза три вопрос. так и не понял, что именно требуется. думаю, если вы подумаете и чётко сформулируете алгоритм (т.е., что и в каких ситуациях вы хотите получить), то сразу и увидите, какой набор комманд его реализует.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82460/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-alexander-barakin).

Answer (score 1):

Вот в этой теме https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648923/git-hook-for-merge-conflicts подсказывают решение.

Можно написать свой скрипт, которой проверяет, является ли конфликтный файл тем самым проблемным. Если да, то разрешает конфликт особым образом. Если нет, то запускает обычный diff3.

И настроить этот скрипт как основной инструмент merge.

Comment: Но это всё равно надо будет руками запускать merge tool?

Comment: Да. И хуками тоже не получится, потому что post-merge срабатывает уже после создания коммита, а значит и после окончания разрешения конфликтов.

Comment: Можно написать свой скрипт, который будете запускать вместо merge, который будет вызывать git merge, и далее делать нужные проверки.