# git автоматически разрешать конфликты в пользу вливаемой ветки

Tags: git, git-merge

Как настроить git так, что бы при мерже ветки, он в определённых папках, всегда, все конфликты, разрешал бы в пользу вливаемой ветки?

*Т.е. по сути просто менял бы содержимое папки на то, что содержится в этой же папке во вливаемой ветке, без всяких мёржей*

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/874889/178576

Comment: Там как то всё запутано, я думал есть простой способ.... Просто мне нужно, тупо, в одной из папок, вместо полноценного мержа который делает гит, просто тупо всё заменять на новые файлы, в не зависимости от изменений конфликтов и т.д. и желательно как то это сохранять в истории гита т.е. как бы делать это через гит, но без всех этих конфликтов..

Comment: «заменить при merge» и «просто заменить» — это две очень большие разницы.

Comment: Пробуйте стратегию `theirs`. И скорее всего придётся делать `merge` ровно столько раз, сколько надо включить или исключить папок из списка (в зависимости от того, что меньше) + 1 (для остатка). Либо, как правильно сослались, писать свои hook'и.